# What is the correct syntax for CSS (multiple ID) + (class)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is the CSS syntax.
I want to add a CLASS(.fade) to multiple ID(titletext1 and titletext2 or more...). The way I write it does not work. What is the correct syntax if I do not want to group them together, not writing them in separate line ?

```js
document.getElementById('titletext1').classList.add('fade');
document.getElementById('titletext2').classList.add('fade');
```

```css
#titletext1.fade,
#titletext2.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext1>This is a Title!!</h1>
<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext2>A second Title!!</h1>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't add a class with CSS, do you it with JavaScript. Please explain.

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.titletext')||[]).forEach(el=>el.classList.add('fade'));` to apply the `fade` class to the elements using javascript

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working?

Comment: `top: 5px` doesn't do anything without a `position:` style. And `opacity: 1` is the default.

Comment: @Barmar It works. turns out i have a typo. Thanks!

Comment: This snippet is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join the two classes together with a `.` separator as `#{id}.{class}.{class}`:

```css
#titletext1.titletext.fade,
#titletext2.titletext.fade {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="titletext fade" id=titletext1>This is a Title!!</h1>
<h1 class="titletext fade" id=titletext2>A second Title!!</h1>

<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext1>Without fade</h1>
<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext2>Without fade</h1>

<h1 class="fade" id=titletext1>Without titletext</h1>
<h1 class="fade" id=titletext2>Without titletext</h1>
```

Though note that without the ID, you can combine the two selectors and still target both elements:

```css
.titletext.fade {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="titletext fade" id=titletext1>This is a Title!!</h1>
<h1 class="titletext fade" id=titletext2>A second Title!!</h1>

<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext1>Without fade</h1>
<h1 class="titletext" id=titletext2>Without fade</h1>

<h1 class="fade" id=titletext1>Without titletext</h1>
<h1 class="fade" id=titletext2>Without titletext</h1>
```

Comment: It should be `.titletext.fade` and you don't need it twice.

Comment: @Barmar - Correct; I'm half-asleep :P Fixed this now.

Comment: THANKS. FIXED!. simply I have some typo.